# Shut down mongod process using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, server, pymongo, shutdown

How do I terminate a mongod process with python using pymongo? Basically, the equivalent of

`use admin
db.shutdownServer()`

which is used in the mongo shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the eval method. Connect to admin database and execute

```
db.eval("db.shutdownServer()")
```

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html

Please be noted though: Can be a security loophole. You should not give admin access to your mongodb instance from the application. That should be handled as part of your deployment steps. Hope it helps.

Comment: can be used for backing up intentions...